# Workmail export job cannot assume role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-workmail

I am trying to programmatically create a workmail export job. I have access to a aws workmail organisation and everything I even created a role that would allow access to the s3 bucket to allow writing into it. I cannot figure out the response I get from the boto describe mailbox export job. It is basically failing but I cannot figure out why.

The questions i also need answered are:

- Where do the mailbox export jobs exist in the aws gui environment because I can get them via the sdk but not on aws console itself.
- What role needs to have the sts:AssumeRole policy? If it's workmail itself I added it to the trusted relationships as a principal but there is still nothing.

I have spent a lot of time changing configurations of the AWS IAM role to allow for different principals to be trusted by the role.

I have some thoughts about my program not having the correct permissions but I do have access to listing users in a mailbox and the like I don't know what I am missing.

Below is the state of the trusted relationships for the role...

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::{My Account}:user/{The username associated with the account}",
                "Service": [
                    "workmail.amazonaws.com",
                    "s3.amazonaws.com"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

The response for one of the jobs I started:

```
{'EntityId': '{entity id}',
 'Description': 'Testing job for mailbox export.',
 'RoleArn': 'arn:aws:iam::{Account}:role/ApiReadRole',
 'KmsKeyArn': 'arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:{Account}:key/{arn Id}',
 'S3BucketName': 'communications',
 'S3Prefix': 'media/private/emails',
 'S3Path': 'media/private/emails/{some id}.zip',
 'EstimatedProgress': 0,
 'State': 'FAILED',
 'ErrorInfo': 'Unable to assume role "arn:aws:iam::{Account}:role/ApiReadRole"',
 'StartTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 2, 8, 48, 9, 642000, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
 'EndTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 2, 8, 48, 11, 121000, tzinfo=tzlocal()),
 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '{some id}',
  'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
  'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '{some id}',
   'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1',
   'content-length': '616',
   'date': 'Fri, 02 Dec 2022 06:48:53 GMT'},
  'RetryAttempts': 0}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed this document and managed to execute the export job.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workmail/latest/adminguide/mail-export.html

But, I was also having a problem that I couldn't run the job successfully.

The reason was that I did not set up key policy on the KMS key which is required to encrypt the exported content on s3 bucket.
Once I configure the key policy, the job ran successfully.

Be sure to have the key policy set up.
This behavior of KMS key is also mentioned in the document below:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policies.html

> No AWS principal, including the account root user or key creator, has any permissions to a KMS key unless they are explicitly allowed, and never denied, in a key policy, IAM policy, or grant.